# Missing template arguments for Request in Boost.Beast

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-beast

Representative code that I try it for http::request is

```
#include <boost/beast/http/message.hpp> 

namespace http = beast::http;
using Request = http::request;
```

but for the last line I obtain "missing template arguments after ‘boost::beast::http::request’" How can be solve this issue?

Comment: `error: use of undeclared identifier 'beast'; did you mean 'boost::beast'?` this is the first error. Have you fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear. `http::request` is a template alias, it requires an argument for the `Body` template first parameter.

```
template <typename Body>
using Request = http::request<Body>;
```